# Importing data to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I have an excel file which contains 4 columns

```
Chapter ID int fk
Subject ID int fk
Title varchar(100)
Description mediumtext
Recap mediumtext
```

The `Description` and `Recap` columns contain `html` syntax. I am currently exporting this data to CSV and then trying to import it into mySQL. However, I receive an error fraying the *"file could not be read"*.

I am guessing this is because of the `,`,`"`, etc, present in the `html` syntax.
Does anyone know how else can the data be imported into mySQL. I do not want to alter the `html` in in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "LOAD DATA INFILE". Look at the doc here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/nodes.csv' INTO TABLE friends_of_friends
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

The `ESCAPED BY '\\'` defines `\` as the escape character. There are two backslashes needed because the backslash is also the standard MySQL escape character.